Including unpublished quotes in research proposals
Currently, I am writing a research proposal for the purpose of obtaining a one-year grant. The proposal centers around a mathematical algorithm that possibly has applications in oncology. As far as I know, this algorithm (or similar ones) have not yet been applied in this medical field. It is therefore not certain what the clinical, biological, or pharmacological applications of such an algorithm could be. My own background lies in mathematics.
In order to substantiate the proposal, I am contacting a number of researchers in oncology and related fields. It is my hope that an expert in any of these fields will help me out a bit, by pointing out a possible medical application of this algorithm. If that happens, I think the proposal could be strengthened by including the relevant quote of this researcher.
However, this quote can likely not be traced back to a specific academic publication of this researcher, as the proposal centers around possible applications that have not yet been described in the literature. The hypothetical quote will probably be part of a message through email.
I was wondering whether it is possible for researchers to link a specific quote - which is not included in one of their academic papers - to one of their digital researcher IDs. These IDs may include their ORCID, Google Scholar, Academia Edu, ArXiv, or some other profile on a venue for digital academic publications. This would allow me to include a quote in the proposal, while at the same time ensure that others can verify the quote indeed comes from an expert in the field.
Does such an application for quote - profile linking exist? If not, are there other solutions one could employ in this situation?


In order to substantiate the proposal, I am contacting a number of researchers in oncology and related fields. It is my hope that an expert in any of these fields will help me out a bit, by pointing out a possible medical application of this algorithm. If that happens, I think the proposal could be strengthened by including the relevant quote of this researcher.

Researchers in biomedical fields are experts in their own right, even if they are not as expert in maths as you. You're asking for their expertise to support your grant.
If you actually want to write a convincing proposal on the applications of some algorithm to a field like oncology, you probably need more than just a quote from someone who studies oncology, you need some level of collaboration with them.
It's common, at least in fields that I work in which include biomedical research, for collaborators to write a Letter of Support (or similar; check the requirements for the specific funding opportunity you are applying for) in favor of the project. In this letter, they will briefly describe who they are (to establish their expertise) and what they can commit to the project. This would be a far stronger way to establish that your algorithm has the interest of people in the applied field than a weakly attributed quote.

Agree -- but I would point out that the exact term of this letter varies by sponsor.  NSF specifically does not want a "Letter of Support" but instead a "Letter of Collaboration".  NSF reserves the right to return without review if you provide a "Letter of Support".  At least in the US, the idea of documenting formal collaborations should exist for almost every federal sponsor, but you may have to look beyond the name and see what they call the mechanism and what the requirements are because it will vary (and could vary within a single sponsor also).

That's an interesting take - thank you. Unfortunately, the deadline for submission for this particular grant has already passed, but I will keep this in mind during subsequent grant applications.

If personA tells you that something exists, then that can be checked, presumably, unless it only exists in unpublished work. So a verification may or may not be even possible. When it is possible, you can also follow up with the source that A names. That can work even for unpublished (not yet published) research.
But if you quote someone in such a case you cite the quotation as [personA: private communication]. In a critical situation, personA can be asked, assuming they are still alive and they may remember or not. But if you retain the email (and you should) then you have a record.
In a research proposal this seems fine and I suspect that it is fairly common for work at the bleeding edge of the known where publication can take a while.

Thank you for your answer - this seems like a reasonable approach. Do you see any value in a digital quote-profile application? I suppose it would be easier to ascertain the source of a quote with such an application
